# add language after installation

Tags: joomla, language

I succesfully installed Civicrm 5.68.0 on Joomla 4.41.
I tried to install the Dutch language as instructed: unzipping languagetarball, creating new subdirectory in components/com_civicrm/civicrm.
I do not see the last subdirectory anymore (it was there in older joomla/civi versions). Only two different subdirectories: /elements and /views??

Checked the documentation, searched the answers in StackExchange: found no information on this.

What do I need to do to add a new language?? Install the l10n directory inside administrator??

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: I don't know much about joomla but it has two civi folders right? Try putting l10n in the other one. Also if switching the language after installing in english, you might find https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/fixoptiontranslations useful.

Answer (score 0):

The l10n-directory resides in **[JOOMLA ROOT]/media/civicrm/l10n**.
I strongly recommend to use the [Update Language Files Extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/uplang).
I tested it on Joomla 4.4.2 and CiviCRM 5.68.0 and can confirm that it works.